# How to read a file in windows 8 metro App

Tags: file-io, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I want to ship a text file along with my App and read it while executing my application. How can I read that particular file? I have set the file to content and copy if newer.

Comment: We already have a tag for Windows 8.  We do not need another.

Comment: I am searching for answers which are applicable to preview version. They are not running on RTM. Some changes have been made in the sdk. Ohkay no problem. Just wanted to make it clear its rtm :)

Comment: @Charles, since i have already created it. Can you make it a synonym tag? If not no problem. It will probably be deleted after a few days if inactive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
private async void ProjectFile()
{
    var _Path = @"Metro.Helpers.Tests\MyFolder\MyFolder.txt";
    var _Folder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;

    var _File = await _Folder.GetFileAsync(_Path);
    var _ReadThis = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(_File);
}
```

Code to read project file which works for me. Hope it helps others too :)

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is heavily dependant on *how* you want to read the file, and what it contains.

You can find a few examples of file access in the [File Access Sample app on MSDN](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/File-access-sample-d723e597/sourcecode?fileId=44740&pathId=962809525), from which one example is:

```
if (file != null) 
{ 
    using (IRandomAccessStream readStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read)) 
    { 
        using (DataReader dataReader = new DataReader(readStream)) 
        { 
            UInt64 size = readStream.Size; 
            if (size <= UInt32.MaxValue) 
            { 
                UInt32 numBytesLoaded = await dataReader.LoadAsync((UInt32)size); 
                string fileContent = dataReader.ReadString(numBytesLoaded); 
                OutputTextBlock.Text = "The following text was read from '" + file.Name + "' using a stream:" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + fileContent; 
            } 
            else 
            { 
                OutputTextBlock.Text = "File " + file.Name + " is too big for LoadAsync to load in a single chunk. Files larger than 4GB need to be broken into multiple chunks to be loaded by LoadAsync."; 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thnx but I found a way. :)
Sorry for leaving that part out.